# Am I using Cauchy's integral formula correctly here?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to evaluate $\int_{C(2,1)}(z^4-\frac{1}{z})dz.$

What I've done so far is note that $\int(z^4-\frac{1}{z})dz=\int_{C(2,1)}\frac{z^5-1}{z}dz$

So if we let $f(z)=z^5-1$

Then we have by Cauchy's Integral formula

$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(2,1)}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C(2,1)}\frac{z^5-1}{z-0}dz$

$\Rightarrow\int_{C(2,1)}\frac{z^5-1}{z}dz=2\pi if(0)=-2\pi i$

This doesn't seem right though , I had thought that it would equal zero because $z_0=0$ is not in $C(2,1)$. Could anyone point out if I've made a mistake ?

Comment: How does $\int(z^4-\frac{1}{z})dz=\int_{C(2,1)}\frac{z^3-1}{z}dz$ work?

Comment: oh my , Ive made such a stupid mistake , you're right of course that makes no sense

Comment: @sharding4 I meant to write $\int(z^4-1/z)=\int \frac{z^5-1}{z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited to remove previous confusion.]

Cauchy's integral formula states that
$$ f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0}dz$$
when $z_0$ is in the *interior* of your simple contour $C$.

However, as you pointed out, $z_0 = 0$ is *not* in the interior of your contour $C(2,1)$, so Cauchy's integral formula does not apply here!

Your second approach, where you appear to be invoking Cauchy's *theorem*, is the correct approach. Since $z^4 - 1/z$ is holomorphic on the open set $U = \mathbb C - \{ 0 \}$, and since $U$ contains the contour $C(2,1)$ and its interior, you are right to conclude that the integral is zero.

Comment: Is there any faster way to show that f(z) is holomorphic than to work out the cauchy Riemann equations ?

Comment: Also how did you show that the radius is 3/2? I'm not familiar with how to prove this ?

Comment: Well, $z^4 - 1/z$ is holomorphic on the disk $B(2, r)$ for any radius $r < 2$. I picked $r = \tfrac 3 2 $ as an example.

Comment: And in response to your first question: $z^4$ is holomorphic everywhere, and $1 / z$ is holomorphic everywhere except at $z = 0$, so it immediately follows that $z^4 - 1 / z$ is holomorphic everywhere except at $z = 0$.