# How to determine all points for which a function f(z) is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

How can one find all of the points of $f(z)$ s.t. $f(z)=z^4-\frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic. 
I tried using the Cauchy-riemann equations , but these are kinda tricky because of the $z^4$ term. Is there a more efficient way ?

I believe from what I've been told that this function is holomorphic on a disk centred at 2 of radius 3/2 but I don't understand how that was figured out ?

Comment: $g(z)=z^4$, being a polynomial, is holomorphic everywhere. $h(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic everywhere except for the origin. Hence, $f(z) = g(z) - h(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere except for the origin.

Comment: @Mark That is what I had originally thought , except that a fellow mathstack exchange member told me that it was only holomorphic on a disk centred at 2 of radius 3/2 , here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738936/am-i-using-cauchys-integral-formula-correctly-here/2738948#2738948 . Is his answer incorrect ?

Comment: He simply chose a disk that contains the contour of integration so that you can apply Cauchy's Theorem. However, the function in question is certainly holomorphic on a larger set, namely the one I mentioned.

Comment: @Mark ah thank God I thought I was missing something extremely crucial , and that he meant for some reason it was only holomorphic on the set he mentioned. But he just meant if it's holomorphic everywhere except (0,0) then its holomorphic on his set and hence because our contour is within both sets we can use Cauchy's theorem ! much clearer now thank you